# Outer Automorphism of $GL(n,F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

**Problem**

Let $\beta$ be a non-trivial aoutomorphism of the field $F$. Use $\beta$ to construct an outer automorphism of $GL(n,F)$. Do all outer automorphisms of $GL(n,F)$ arise in this way?

**My attempt**

What do we know? We know that $\beta$ is a bijective homomorphism and non-trivial.

Observation: Center of $GL(n,F) = \{aI_n\},\ a\in F$. So we need a map that doesn't fix the elements in the center because we need to find an outer automorphism (not inner automorphish)

Let us consider the map

$\phi:\ GL(n,F) \rightarrow GL(n,F) $

$a I_n \mapsto \beta(a) I_n$

We need to show that $\phi$ is an outer automorphism.

To show that $\phi$ is bijective is trivial, it follows from the fact that $\beta $
 is bijective.

$\phi$ is a homomorphism:

$\phi(aI_nbI_n)=\phi(abI_n)=\beta(ab)I_n=\beta(a)\beta(b)I_n= \beta(a)I_n\beta(b)I_n = \phi(aI_n)\phi(bI_n)$

And finally $\phi$ is an outer automorphism:

We need to show that it is not inner, that is that it does not fix elements of the Center.

$\phi(aI_n)=\beta(a)I_n\neq a I_n$, since $\beta(a) \neq a\ , \forall \ a \in F$ by the assumption.

**Question**

Please correct me if I am wrong in some part of the proof and I am stuck in "Do all outer automorphisms of $GL(n,F)$ arise in this way?". My guess is that all the automorphism arise in this way since this the only way I can think of, when constructing function which doesn't fix elements of Center.

Comment: Where does $\phi$ send elements of $GL(n, F)$ that aren't of the form $aI_n$?

Comment: It is not true that $\beta(\alpha)\neq\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in F$. In fact this is impossible by the very definition of a homomorphism, as $\beta(0)=0$ and $\beta(1)=1$.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think about this. I was just trying to construct an outer automorphism. Thank you for your question.

Comment: Also, I do not understand what is meant by the final part of the question *"Do all automorphisms of $\operatorname{GL}(n,F)$ arise in this way?"* In what way? And do you mean *all* automorphisms, or all *outer* automorphisms, or just all elements of the outer automorphism group?

Comment: @Servaes Yes I meant outer automorphisms, sorry. I Made an edit

Comment: Could you please give me a hint, if my solution is not right?

Comment: An outer automorphism means an automorphism modulo inner automorphism. It's a recurrent confusion with "non-inner automorphism".

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is no, because the outer automorphism that maps each matrix $A$ to $(A^{\mathrm T})^{-1}$ (inverse of transpose) does not arise in this way. (This can also be seen as the graph automorphism of the $A_{n-1}$ Coxeter diagram, which is associated with this group.)

This map induces $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ on the centre of the group (the scalar matrices). This shows that it is an outer automorphism whenever $|F| > 2$. In fact it is an inner automorphism on ${\rm GL}(2,2) \cong S_3$, but outer on ${\rm GL}(n,2)$ for $n>2$, because it maps stabilizers of spaces of dimension $k$ to stabilizers of spaces of dimension $n-k$.

Comment: And the construction of outer automorphism? If you know how to construct an outer automorphism, could you please help?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I defined an outer automorphism  in the above answer.

Comment: So you are saying that the map $A \mapsto A^{\perp}^{-1}$ is an outer automorphism? It can not be an outer one because it fixes the center, am I mistaken? And in the exercise it says to construct an outer automorphism using map $\beta$. I am just asking is my proof of that part is correct?

Comment: Yes I am saying that the map $A \mapsto (A^{\rm T})^{-1}$ is an outer automorphism. See my edit to the answer. The question you asked was "do all outer automorphisms arise in this way?" and the answer is no, except when $n=|F|=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: One more question, I got comments above that my proof for the part "Use $\beta$" to construct and outer automorphism is not correct. Could you please help me to construct and outer automorpshism of $GL(n,F)$ using $\beta$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you haven't actually defined the map $\phi$ that (presumably) is supposed to be induced by the field automorphism $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

let $\phi$ sent $( a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ to $(\beta (a_{ij}))_{n\times n}$, then you can proof that it's an outer automorphism of $GL(n,F)$